# Ip segments of amazon work space

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cloud

I am trying to request firewall for accessing amazon work space.
I need to know the ip segment of amazon work space.

I will be connecting to Asia region so need to open the firewall for Asia region.

Could you please let me know how to get the ip segments of amazon work spaces?

I tried looking into https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json but I am not seeing it for Singapore region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Singapore is **ap-southeast-1**

See here: [Regions and Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so look like I will have open firewall for nearly 18 ip segment for EC2 alone.